# Solr exact word search

Tags: search, solr

I want to configure my Solr search engine so I get an exact match for the search term I enter.

eg. 'taxes' should return documents with 'taxes' and not 'tax', 'taxation' etc.

Any help or tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I presume  your field is a TextField, by default solr does a fuzzy search on this field. What you want is to set up your field as a string field and add no tokenizer then you'll get an exact match.

You can even combine the exact search with a fuzzy search and use DisMax to boost the relative weights.

Example  (schema.xml) :

```
<field name="name"             type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" required="true" />
<field name="nameString"       type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" required="true" />
<copyField source="name" dest="nameString"/>
```

Example (solrconfig.xml) :

```
<requestHandler name="accounts" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="defType">dismax</str>
      <str name="qf">
        nameString^10.0 name^5.0 description^1.0
      </str>
      <str name="tie">0.1</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

Comment: Is this possible at query time, with a special operator? Like =taxes

Comment: @mlissner, The above XML is simply default parameters which are added to the query. U could have done so by adding to your query defType=dismax&qa=nameString^10.0 name^5.0 description^1.0 etc etc

Comment: @ItayMoav, the goal is to have the *users* be able to place the exact match query.

Comment: Yes, I understood you. If u know u can add those params to query, you can put a UI on top that will generate the query...

Answer (score 7):

To turn off stemming in your schema.xml, you can define text field like this:

```
<types>

   <!-- other fields definition -->

   <fieldType name="text_no_stem" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
      <analyzer>
          <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
          <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
          <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
   </fieldType>

   <!-- other fields definition -->

</types>

<fields>

   <!-- other fields definition -->

   <dynamicField name="*_nostem" type="text_no_stem" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

   <!-- other fields definition -->

</fields>
```

I'm using [sunspot](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot) to integrate solr with Ruby on Rails. With this in the schema.xml I define my searchable block like this:

```
searchable do
    text(:wants, as: :wants_nostem)
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Turn off [stemming](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#Stemming).

Comment: Thanks Hank, maybe I should have phrased my question more appropriately, How do I disable stemming? :)

Comment: see http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Exact-match-on-a-field-with-stemming-tt2808086.html#a2809293

Comment: sometimes re-index could be painful, especially if it took a long time on big data. Is there another way around instead of turning off stemming?

Answer (score 4):

Use the quotes for exact match result :

Example :

core Name : core1
Key : namestring

http://localhost:8983/solr/core1/select?q=namestring:"taxes"&wt=json&indent=true

Answer (score 2):

Use solr string field whcih will do an exact value search e.g

```
<fieldType class="solr.StrField" name="string" omitNorms="true" sortMissingLast="true" />
```