# What is the difference between city:Athens vs city:*Athens* ? in the q box of Solr Admin panel?

Tags: solr

What is the difference between `city:Athens` vs `city:*Athens*` , in the q box of Solr Admin panel. Why are the results fetched different (asterisc results are greater in numbers). Is one super set of the other or are they entirely different sets ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asterisk brings the super set of the other i.e. it will bring all the results containing the word athens

```
for ex:city:*Athens* will bring results like heathens, preathens ,athens is good
while city:Athens will bring the results like athens is good.
```

Using wild cards can cause problems at times this links provides the knowledge of how the solr handles the wildcards:http://lucidworks.com/blog/whats-with-lowercasing-wildcard-multiterm-queries-in-solr/

And this is one of the common problems when using wildcards:
[Solr: Using a wildcard on a string with whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12378872/solr-using-a-wildcard-on-a-string-with-whitespace)