# Solr - fq multiple syntax

Tags: solr, sharding

I have a query that is not working.

I have two catalogs with the same fields and I am filtering by two of them, the field COUNTRY and the field CATEGORY, I just want the results where COUNTRY is equal to "ar" and CATEGORY start with "/Life And Style" OR start with "/vidayestilo"

Example: `http://dominio.com:8080/solr/collation1/select?q=casa&shards=dominio.com:8080/solr/collation1,dominio.com:8080/solr/collation2&fq=COUNTRY:ar&fq=CATEGORY:(\/Life Y Style* OR \/vidayestilo*)`

The above request returns no results.

If I change the filters: `&fq=COUNTRY:ar&fq=CATEGORY:"\/Life And Style"*`.
Returns 6065 results. Only return results if I use quotes `"\/Life And Style"*`

If I change the filters: `&fq=COUNTRY:ar&fq=CATEGORY:\/vidayestilo*`
Returns 1451 results. No need to use quotes `\/vidayestilo*`

Conclusion 1: I have to use quotes when there are spaces, so I based this theory i did the following request:

```
http://dominio.com:8080/solr/collation1/select?q=casa&shards=dominio.com:8080/solr/collation1,dominio.com:8080/solr/collation2&fq=COUNTRY:ar&fq=CATEGORY:("\/Life Y Style"* OR \/vidayestilo*)
```

It does not work because it returns 6065, only returns results for `"\/Life And Style"*`. Even if I add quotes to `"\/vidayestilo"*`, I have the same result.

And when I put in the first place "/vidayestilo"*: `&fq=CATEGORY:("\/vidayestilo"* OR "\/Life And Style"*)` returns 1451 results.

The correct is return 7516 Results (1451 + 6065), I dont know if this is happening by the spaces between Life Y Style because in this case I have to use quotation marks but it does not work when I use it in parentheses with OR.

I appreciate any help in this.

Answer (score 0):

I found this interesting post that helped me solve my problem ;)
[Solr wildcard query with whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10023133/solr-wildcard-query-with-whitespace)