# Solr wildcard query with whitespace and synonym

Tags: solr, whitespace, synonym

This problem is like this:[Solr wildcard query with whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10023133/solr-wildcard-query-with-whitespace)
I have a wildcard query that looks something like:

`q=location:los a*`

I'd like it to match "los angeles" and "los altos". A query like:

`q=location:los\ a*`

Works fine, but if I have a synonym logic:(synonym.txt)

`los,las`

And use "los l*" to match "las lu".Seems not work.How can I do this?

The fileType and file config:

`<fieldType name="ngram" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" stemEnglishPossessive="0" generateWordParts="0" generateNumberParts="0" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnNumerics="0" preserveOriginal="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonym.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="25"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" stemEnglishPossessive="0" generateWordParts="0" generateNumberParts="0" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnNumerics="0" preserveOriginal="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>`

`<field name="location" type="ngram" indexed="true" stored="false"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this is a version problem. I use Solr 4.0 in my project, but when I upgrade the Solr version to 5.4.1, the synonym logic works fine.

I haven't change the query analyzer. It's for special requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You used `solr.SynonymFilterFactory` for indexing not for query analyzer so

when you search for `"los l*"` it looks for terms starting with los not "las".
use analyzer for query

Add this line to your query analyzer

```
<filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
```

Hope this works