# How to enforce an exact match to get the highest priority?

Tags: solr, lucene, solr-query-syntax, solr-schema

I am indexing and searching 5 fields, which are tokenized/filtered in various ways.
BUT, I would like that when I search, if the query I entered matches a value in field 1, it will be the top result I get back.
How would I define:

1. The field
2. The query in such a way this field gets priority IF there is 100% match

In my schema, I have the field

```
<field name="na_title" type="text_names" indexed="true" stored="false" required="true" />
```

text_names is :`<fieldType name="text_names" class="solr.StrField" />`

I have **ONLY one** entry with na_title="somthing is going on here". But, when I search 
`text_names:somthing is going on here` I get many results.
Just to point it out, there are no analyzers nor filters on that field, both for query and index actions.

Answer (score 1):

From the [manual](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_1/scoring.html#Score%20Boosting):

> Lucene allows influencing search results by "boosting" in more than
>   one level:
>
> - Document level boosting - while indexing - by calling
>     document.setBoost() before a document is added to the index.
> - Document's Field level boosting - while indexing - by calling
>     field.setBoost() before adding a field to the document (and before
>     adding the document to the index).
> - Query level boosting - during
>     search, by setting a boost on a query clause, calling
>     Query.setBoost().

Comment: I boosted the field that holds the title ^20 as well when I query that field, did not help.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to index the field twice -- once analyzed and once not. Then you can boost the matches in the nonanalyzed fields over the others.

A shortcut could be to index all those fields as strings and use copyfield to copy them as text into a catch-all field. That would simplify the query a little and decrease the number of duplicate fields.

Comment: Do the additional results contain any part of your query or are they just random documents?  I would run that string through the analysis page and make sure that is truly is unanalyzed. Also, debugQuery might shed some light on where those extra results are coming from.

Comment: Solution here woks, saw that before your comment...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630879/solr-exact-word-search