# Solr exact word result come first

Tags: java, solr, lucene, solrj, solr-boost

In Solr-5.0.0, I have one `product_name` field. When I search for a word or more than words, its giving results with product names that contain the words. How can I make it as the exact match come first.

My **Schema.xml** is below:

```xml
<field name="product_name" type="text_wslc" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false"/>
```

and my field definition is also given below:

```xml
<fieldType name="text_wslc" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                             generateWordParts="1"
                             generateNumberParts="1"
                             catenateWords="1"
                             catenateNumbers="1"
                             catenateAll="1"
                             preserveOriginal="1"
                             />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" />
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KStemFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                             generateWordParts="1"
                             generateNumberParts="1"
                             catenateWords="1"
                             catenateNumbers="1"
                             catenateAll="1"
                             preserveOriginal="1"
                             />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" />
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KStemFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Any boosting needed at index time or query time? Or any thing else?

Comment: You are looking for query time boosting using Dismax. Check this https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin#pf_.28Phrase_Fields.29  also see examples at the end of the page.

Comment: This post could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630879/solr-exact-word-search

Comment: @jay I have added one more copyFiled

Comment: @jay I have added one more copyFiled
<fieldType name="string_ci" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
      <analyzer type="query">
   <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
   <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
 then i queried like this but it wont give the expected result
http://localhost:8983/solr/Dummy2/select?q=(laptop bag)&qf=nameSrting^222+product_name^0.1&defType=dismax
nameSrting is the copy field of product_name 
why?