# What is the best practice to write a search query for SOLR for an ecommerce website

Tags: mysql, solr

It is my first project using SOLR, I have indexed the all products in solr and created a copyField named searchable. Copied field like product_title, description, categories titles, filters in this field.

I am using query given below to get results.

http://localhost:8080/solr/testcore/select?indent=on&q=status:1 AND is_single:0 AND searchable:sleeve+medium AND seller_status:1&wt=json

I am getting the matching results but couple of questions I have:

1. Is there any mechanism to sort result by exact match on top
2. I indexed the quantity and stock status of product, Can I give low weightage to products which have quantity = 0 or stock_status = 'Out of Stock" so out of stock items always display in bottom of search.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer to your first question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630879/solr-exact-word-search).
About the second question, using eDismax you can use the boost query (bq) value:

```
bq=stock_status:"Out of Stock"^-0.1
```

in general though is better to boost important documents than de-boost docs with low importance.