# Precise expression or word solr match

Tags: solr

I am looking for way to match a very specific expression or word in my solr collection.
Here is an example :
I want the query to return me :
"Paris"
And not : "Paris is great"
And not : "I like Paris"

Thanks :)

Comment: Maybe this stackoverflow question might help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630879/solr-exact-word-search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want exact matches, make sure the field type is defined as `string`. A `string` field will not do any tokenization or use any filters, and will only generate hits when the query is exactly the same as the value indexed.

Comment: I changed my schema.xml to define the field type as string, but even after restarting Solr, the results do not match exactly. Am I doing something wrong here ?

Comment: You'll have to reindex before the results will change.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use KeywordTokenizer

> This tokenizer treats the entire text field as a single token

https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/tokenizers.html#Tokenizers-KeywordTokenizer