# Solr seach exact match return without modifying configuration file

Tags: solr

Using solr search version 3.4. Is it possible to search exact matching phrase from the
solr collection. For eg: if the word searched is 'kitchen sink',right now it returns records
containing either kitchen or sink somewhere present.

Would like to get only those records with matching having given search criteria without modifying
the solr config files.ie,is it possible to manage from the request using any operators?

Any guidance will be really helpful.

Thanks

Comment: You can use a phrase query: `"kitchen sink"~1` - which means that the words will occur within one position of each other. You'll still get hits where `sink` comes in front of `kitchen`, but those will be rather few. Instead, you should define a field as a `string` field type, but you can't do that without changing the configuration file and reindexing your content.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I made some changes to config file referring link 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630879/solr-exact-word-search'. But when the collection was repopulated,all the custom made changes were gone. It will be helpful if can provide guidance about how and what all changes to be made in config file to achieve the  exact full  word match.

Comment: It might seem you didn't edit the configuration you were supposed to edit - if you're running in cloud mode, the configuration is stored in Zookeeper. Make sure the fields are defined as you expect (and any copy field rules are active) by looking at the schema under the Solr admin page before re-importing. Unless you have the copy field instructions, there will be no content added to your new fields.